# Switch from PHP to Java or .Net

Tags: java, php

I currently run a website on LAMP, I am currently in the process of refactoring my code from normal php to Zend framework with Doctrine. I am happy with setup but often find function not found errors on live site cause I have renamed function. Which is frustrating as most of time is wasted is patching these errors.
So I have decided to switch from php to java as the code gets compiled, so just error will not go to live site. With java netbeans will work better.

But as I have not been in touch to j2ee for many years. What is the best replacement for my above setup in java?

- Option 1. Jsf 2 with Hibernate
- Option 2. Seam
- Option 3. Spring
- Option 4. Struts with Hibernate

My server has 24 gig ram and 2 core i7 processor and ssd drive on raid 0

Will my server handle the same amount of visitors if java was used without any performance issues?

I like the way I can update my site without losing live sessions(logged-in users). Can I do the same in Java? from my experience each update to site will redeploy the App which resets all the Active Sessions.

I love to consider .Net but from what I have read on most forums, no one recommends it?

Kind regards

Zerone

Comment: So to clear it up, you have poorly coded site and you decided to swap to Java because code gets compiled? Now.. what makes you think that someone won't code your site poorly in Java? Note: yes, Java code does execute faster than PHP one. However, we're talking miniscule improvements (can you note the difference between 1msec and 0.5 msec?). Social networking sites often experience the bottleneck in reads and writes from the data store (in your case MySQL) which are solved by distributing reads and writes and leveraging the db layer by using caching systems such as Memcached.

Comment: What makes you think that renaming a function in Java is any easier? You'd have to go and change the function reference everywhere it appears in your source code AND recompile the whole thing as well.

Comment: @Marc B At least in java, with the required re-compilation, he'll catch all references at compile time, so errors won't pop up on the live site.

Comment: think it like this: with the money invested into rewriting the whole website into another language you may buy another webserver, and do some sort of load-balancing between them. This will lead to a speddier website without the hurdles of rewriting. Also, you may aswell write a bad website with poorly named functions in any language, no matter if its compiled or not.

Comment: @Aleks: these "error" might very easily get catched if he'd use find in files, or refactor, or function aliases, or unit tests. Alternatives exists, but for some reason he ain't using them

Comment: Switching to Java from PHP will indeed allow you to catch some errors at compile time that you sometimes don't catch until runtime in PHP. There is a certain amount of "safety" granted by using a language that can check dependencies at compile time. That being said, one of the costs of using Java is that it generally takes longer to develop in, sometimes a lot longer. Tradeoffs. (I'll note that I prefer a dynamic language for front end development for front end work and a static/compiled language for back end work)

Comment: Well written PHPDoc and a good IDE helps doing safe delete of functions/methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is not switching to Java from PHP your problem is an good test coverage via unit and in particular with integration tests. From what you wrote the best thing might be to take a look at Selenium and to automate testing as most as possible. You need a complete infrastructure to deploy to a test system and run integration tests on it (Selenium) and after that you can say everything is ok.

Comment: Well unit test takes loadz of time and thinking to write, but then do i have to write unit test for the unit tests?

Comment: Also PHP is too forgiving and forces you to write untidy code. I also hate writing /***@var and /***@return, which sometimes works and other times doesn't.

Comment: Hm...I have written long time PHP (6 Years) as well as Java (in the meantime 7 Years Java) so the difference is only sitting in front of the keyboard. If you are writing good code it doesn't matter in which language your are writing the code. There exist many techniques which support in writing good code. If you you like to rewrite the code it will take a long time to get the state of the current PHP implementation and longer to come to the tested state of the current PHP code..I think the best investment it to write integration tests and than refactor the code. This improves quality.

Answer (score 1):

Java will perform better, but switching to Java seems like overkill for this situation. That said, I would recommend something based on Spring and Hibernate. Spring can be a real godsend for configuring just about anything in Java and Hibernate is similar to Doctrine.

Apache Tapestry would make a good presentation toolkit for your site. It's a great templating library that is cleaner than JSP.

Comment: so can I use tomcat as server, Spring for business logic, Hibernate for models and Apache Tapestry for front end?

Answer (score 0):

Java has a large variety of solutions to the same problem.  Currently, the mainline Java solution to presenting items on the web is Java Server Faces.

Older (which doesn't always mean worse) solutions include Struts, Apache Tapestry, (parts of) Spring, etc.  These solutions benefit from maturity, having an established following, etc.  Basically they are good solutions because people already know the points where they fail, and already know how to work around them.  The new solutions attempt to remove these pain points, and thus suffer from new pain points.  Think of it as not noticing your headache until after you fix your broken arm.

Java will perform much better because the code that delivers the web pages is already in memory, so it avoids a number of items that take time (process spawning, disk access, webserver to language engine communications, etc).  There are other PHP solutions which also attempt to solve similar problems using similar techniques; however, PHP has a different coding background and style.  For example, Java doesn't need to discard any state between web page requests, something that PHP does (and often uses a number of libraries and workarounds to mitigate).

My recommendation is to use Java, but realize that a direct port will incur a lot of unnecessary expense.  Choose a web facing toolkit (JavaServerFaces is the newest and part of the Java EE standard), and start off by porting the static portions of the HTML web pages.  Organize your requests by scope (how long the side effect of the request should persist), and use the Servlet standard to store the artifacts generated by the request in the appropriate application, session, request, etc scope.

On the database side of things, there are many standards and solutions to pick from too.  Personally, as you don't have a lot of legacy concerns, I would go with JPA.  While it is not really a 100% complete solution, it will push you to use an interface which can be replaced by better implementations over time, without the need to recode your application.  By stating it isn't 100% complete, I mean that you need to select a JPA provider as the default provider probably won't meet your real-world production needs.  That said, the default provider should sustain development oriented work, and JPA's standards should protect you from unexpected differences when you run the code against different environments.

Whether you wish to fully restructure you code into a Java EE multi-tier architecture, of if you just want to embed a large Servlet (server faces is a type of servlet solution) that does everything is more of a function of how much you wish to architect your code.  It is not a porting problem.  That said, the biggest benefits of a typical Java solution over a typical PHP solution is that the Java architecture is designed to work faster and provide more features out-of-the-box.  If you intend to do a port with no rearchitecting, you might be better off just finding out the bottlenecks in the PHP code and fixing them.

Comment: So from your experience my server should be able to perform fine if I switch to J2EE.

Comment: From my experience, you will have the ability to speed up things dramatically as you switch to J2EE; however, the worst performance problems don't come from the language, they come from wasteful coding.  You will likely see some performance boost in parts, and performance loss in others, balancing out to a moderate performance gain.  However, when you then start to restructure your code in the new environment, you will then see dramatic gains.  Java has more performance oriented tools around it, so it's easier to see where the bottlenecks are (and fix them).

Answer (score -1):

if you dont use ajax, i prefer 4 (struts + hibernate):

- jsf needs an little bit of expiriences on such heavy load (getter-methods must be fast and so on).

if you use ajax, i prefer an combination of 3 and 1

regards
peter